# Input/Output for EmrActivity - AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to use Data Pipeline to run a Spark Application. How can I access the input / output I specify (S3DataNode) for the EmrActivity, inside my Spark application?

My question is similar to this - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=507877

Earlier I used to pass the input and output as arguments to the Spark application in steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran across the same question. There's very limited documentation around this. This is my understanding:

1. You specify the `input` and `output` for the EmrActivity. This will create the dependencies between the data nodes and the activity.
2. In the EmrActivity, you can reference the input sources like this: `#{input.directoryPath},#{output.directoryPath}`

Example:

```
    ... 
    {
      "name": "Input Data Node",
      "id": "inputDataNode",
      "type": "S3DataNode",
      "directoryPath": "s3://my/raw/data/path"
    },
    {
      "name": "transform",
      "id": "transform",
      "type": "EmrActivity",          
      "step": [
        "s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,s3://my/transform/script.sh,#{input.directoryPath},#{output.directoryPath}"
      ],
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "emrcluster"
      },
      "input": {
        "ref": "inputDataNode"
      },
      "output": {
        "ref": "outputDataNode"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Output Data Node",
      "id": "outputDataNode",
      "type": "S3DataNode",           
      "directoryPath": "s3://path/to/output/"
    },
    ...
```